# Color Box Child Window value

Tags: jquery, colorbox

This seem to be simple , but it almost took 3 hours of time, still didn't get the solution

I have a colorbox plugin where I go from main page to other page using the color box,I mean when I click on a button a popup is opened with a new page which have a dropdown and  when I click the button or the color box in the popup  , I just want the selected value in the pop up to the main page , so that using that value I can do manipulation to move further

Here is the code I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.PopUp').colorbox({
            iframe: true,
            innerWidth: 250,
            innerHeight: 150,
            onClosed: function () {
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Popup is opened with new page but I didn't get how to return the value of the dropdown from the popup when I click the close button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to access the parent of the iFrame and set some DOM element to the value of the drop down so you can the retrieve it in your onClosed: function.

So, in your iFrame add some script to do something like this

```
<script>

   $('#completedAction').onClick(function() {
      var selectedValue = $('#dropdown option:selected').val();

      $('#domElementWhereYouWantToStoreValueOnParent', window.parent.document).val(selectedValue);

      parent.$.fn.colorbox.close(); //Close Colorbox

   });

</script>
```

Then on your onClosed function you can retrive the value like this:

```
var valueFromiFrame = $("#domElementWhereYouWantToStoreValueOnParent").val();
```

Good luck.

Comment: Good one but actually I require the url to which it is redirected after click on the button of the iframe, so for that, I have taken an element on the parent and overwrite it in the iframe with that present location, and I used that element in closed function of the main frame